# How do I remove elections?

Tags: tropico-3

In Tropico 3, how do I remove elections? A major demand for the Loyalists is to remove elections to get them to vote for me.

Comment: Typical Tropico... Remove election and we'll vote for you... vote in what???

Comment: Vote for me in the term-like elections for El Presidente. I've been getting a good relationship with my people and they want me to remove them.

Comment: If you provide an exact screenshot of the quest I can probably refine my answer but based on the available information, I gave my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to issue the [Martial Law Edict](http://tropico.wikia.com/wiki/Edicts_(Tropico_3)) (scroll down or Ctrl-F) which postpones all elections until the edict is lifted or the "Free Elections" edict is active. However, this does decrease your production, liberty and tourism rating and increase crime..

```
Martial Law
Cost: $5,000
Requires: 60% Respect from Militarists
Effects:
  * Decreases Crime Safety, Liberty, and tourism rating.
  * Decreases all Production
  * No elections will be held (unless "Free Elections" condition is active).
```